# How to apply the orient function on the geometry of a GeoPandas dataframe

Tags: shapely, geopandas

Given a GeoDataFrame where the `geometry` column contains both Polygons and MultiPolygons.

How can I force the orientation (left-hand-rule or right-hand-rule) on these geometries?

Answer (score 2):

The orient functionality is included within shapely as function in the `ops` module from version `1.7a2` and onwards.

If you have this function you can do the following:

```py
from shapely.ops import orient # version >=1.7a2
gdf.geometry = gdf.geometry.apply(orient, args=(-1,))
```

If you have an earlier version of shapely and cannot update to the latest version, try to emulate this new functionality with the following function:

```
from shapely.geometry.base import BaseMultipartGeometry
from shapely.geometry.polygon import orient as orient_
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

def orient(geom, sign=1.0):
    if isinstance(geom, BaseMultipartGeometry):
        return geom.__class__(
            list(
                map(
                    lambda geom: orient(geom, sign),
                    geom.geoms,
                )
            )
        )
    if isinstance(geom, (Polygon,)):
        return orient_(geom, sign)
    return geom

gdf.geometry = gdf.geometry.apply(orient, args=(-1,))
```

Comment: the `geom.__class__` bit is clever! I like it. A bit of note on dataframe best practices: while assigning dataframe columns with the dot-accessor _works_, it's not a good habit to have as you could overwrite the dataframe's methods or properties (for instance if you had a column called "max"). Best practice would be to use the `.assign` method (`gdf = gdf.assign(geometry=gdf.loc[:, 'geometry'].apply(orient, args=(1,)))`). Certainly more verbose, but safer and easier to incorporate into a longer chain of commands